# Gen Fill Rates on Varying Nested Dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, loops, counting

I have a process that receives nested dictionaries in Python:

Example Nested Dictionary Schema (pseudocode)

```
key1: value1,
key2: dict(
  key3: value2,
  key4: value3,
),
key5: list(value4,value5) # any value is fine, just not empty or null
```

Example Nested Dictionary Data (pseudocode)

```
key1: 'value',
key2: dict(
  key3: '',
  key4: 12345,
),
key5: list()
```

I want to iterate over/scan this dict and check if each key has a value (is not Null or blank - false/0 are ok). I will need to scan a bunch of identical dicts to get an overall "fill rate" for that set of dicts. The process sees sets of dicts with different formats every time it's run, so it needs to automatically generate the fill rate report:

Example Fill Rate for the Single Nested Example Above (ideally a flat dict):

```
key1: 1
key2: 1
key2-key3: 0
key2-key4: 1
key5: 0
```

If we scanned ten dicts of the same structure, for example, we might see a :fill rate" like this:

```
key1: 5
key2: 6
key2-key3: 6
key2-key4: 4
key5: 3
```

**Questions**

1. What is the most pythonic way to scan dicts of varying structure to gen a fill rate? Is there a more efficient way if I have to do this millions of times?
2. What is the most pythonic way to create a flat dict to store the counts and how do I update it?

Comment: Just to clarify: by "fill rate" you mean you want to see, out of all the dictionaries you end up seeing, how many times e.g. `key1` is specified? Your example is unclear.

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully be more clear. Gen means: check every field and count as "filled" if it's set and not Null or blank. By fillrate, I mean how often are each key-value pair not null or empty across a set of dicts with the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

> What is the most pythonic way to scan dicts of varying structure to gen a fill rate?

Recursively. In particular, I return results of the walked subtree to the caller. The caller is responsible for merging multiple subtrees into its own tree's results.

> Is there a more efficient way if I have to do this millions of times?

Probably. Try one solution and see if it is A) Correct and B) fast enough. If it is both, don't bother looking for most efficient.

> What is the most pythonic way to create a flat dict to store the counts and how do I update it?

By using one of the libraries that come with Python. In this case, `collections.Counter()`. And by calling its `.update()` function.

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

example1_dict = {
    'key1': 'value',
    'key2': {
        'key3': '',
        'key4': 12345,
    },
    'key5': list()
}

example2_dict = {
    'key1': 'value',
    'key7': {
        'key3': '',
        'key4': 12345,
    },
    'key5': [1]
}

def get_fill_rate(d, path=()):
    result = Counter()
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result[path+(k,)] += 1
            result.update(get_fill_rate(v, path+(k,)))
        elif v in (False, 0):
            result[path+(k,)] += 1
        elif v:
            result[path+(k,)] += 1
        else:
            result[path+(k,)] += 0
    return result

def get_fill_rates(l):
    result = Counter()
    for d in l:
        result.update(get_fill_rate(d))
    return dict(result)

result = get_fill_rates([example1_dict, example2_dict])

# Raw result
pprint(result)

# Formatted result
print('\n'.join(
    '-'.join(single_key for single_key in key) + ': ' + str(value)
    for key, value in sorted(result.items())))
```

Result:

```
{('key1',): 2,
 ('key2',): 1,
 ('key2', 'key3'): 0,
 ('key2', 'key4'): 1,
 ('key5',): 1,
 ('key7',): 1,
 ('key7', 'key3'): 0,
 ('key7', 'key4'): 1}
key1: 2
key2: 1
key2-key3: 0
key2-key4: 1
key5: 1
key7: 1
key7-key3: 0
key7-key4: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I solved it. I did some very minor testing, but I think this works:

```
def scan_dict(d):
    counts = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            subcounts = scan_dict(v)
            for subkey, subcount in subcounts.items():
                new_key = str(k) + "-" + str(subkey)
                count = counts.get(new_key, 0)
                counts[new_key] = count + subcount
        key = str(k)
        count = counts.get(key, 0)
        counts[key] = count + 1
    return counts

def scan_all_dicts(ds):
    total_counts = {}
    for d in ds:
        counts = scan_dict(d)
        for k, v in counts.items():
            count = total_counts.get(k, 0)
            total_counts[k] = count + v
    return total_counts
```

Essentially, there's a recursive function to scan each dictionary and count everything inside it and any children dicts it finds.

The "driver" is the second function, which takes an iterable (e.g. list) of dicts and runs them all through the first function, and then returns a flattened list of all the values.

I did not check the values to ensure they're "not blank"; I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is the most Pythonic way to approach this problem; however, this solution utilizes a decorator to update a global dictionary to store the overall fill-rate. Using a `collections.defaultdict`, `final_dict` can be updated many times with each wrap of `get_occurences`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
final_dict = defaultdict(int)
def fill(f):
   def update_count(structure, last):
     data = f(structure, last=None)
     def update_final(d):
        for a, b in d.items():
            global final_dict
            final_dict[a] += int(bool(b)) if not isinstance(b, dict) else int(bool(update_final(b)))
      update_final(data)
   return update_count

@fill
def get_occurences(d, last=None):
   return {"{}-{}".format(last, a) if last else a:int(bool(b)) if not isinstance(b, dict) else get_occurences(b, a) for a, b in d.items()}

structures = [{'key1':'value', 'key2':{'key3':'', 'key4':12345}, 'key5':[]}, {'key1':18, 'key2':'value1', 'key3':['James', 'Bob', 'Bill']},{'key1':'value2', 'key2':{'key3':'233', 'key4':12345}, 'key5':100}]
for structure in structures:
   get_occurences(structure)

for i in sorted(final_dict.items(), key=lambda (c, d):(int(re.findall('\d+$', c)[0]), bool(re.findall('\w+-\w+', c)))):
  print("{}: {}".format(*i))
```

Output:

```
{'key2-key3': 1, 'key2-key4': 2, 'key1': 3, 'key2': 1, 'key5': 1, 'key3': 1}
```

Output:

```
key1: 3
key2: 1
key3: 1
key2-key3: 1
key2-key4: 2
key5: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
example1_dict = {
    'key1': 'value',
    'key2': {
        'key3': '',
        'key4': 12345,
    },
    'key5': list()
}



example={}
for ka,l in example1_dict.items():
    if isinstance(l,dict):
        def hi(fg, track=''):
            print(fg)
            for i, k in fg.items():
                track="{}-{}".format(ka,i)
                if i not in example:
                    example[track] = 1
                else:
                    example[track] += 1
                if isinstance(k, dict):
                    return hi(k)



        print(hi(l))
    elif l:
        example[ka]=1
    else:
        example[ka]=0
print(example)
```

output:

```
{'key5': 0, 'key2-key4': 1, 'key1': 1, 'key2-key3': 1}
```